# Stencyl.Desktop not working

Tags: .desktop

I have installed Stencyl on ubuntu and it is perfectly working fine from terminal commands, after making some amendments in Stencyl file. Now i want to make desktop entry for the Stencyl and wish to put the icon in the launchpad, i have prepared stencyl.desktop in /usr/share/applications/   as

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Stencyl
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/Stencyl/Stencyl
Terminal=true
Icon=/opt/Stencyl/icon.xpm
Comment=Game Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE
Name[en]=stencyl.desktop
```

and have drag and drop to the launchpad, Icon is not executing Stencyl application, if i run the same application from terminal, it is working fine and giving following results also

```
amulbhatia@Nadar:/opt/Stencyl$ ./Stencyl
[LOG] The Stencyl workspace is: /home/amulbhatia/
[LOG] lang/locales.txt
[LOG] Locales: {de=German, it=Italian, test=test, pt=Portuguese, fr=French, en=English, ru=Russian, gr=Greek, es=Spanish}
[LOG] Reading... global-phrases
[LOG] Bad - Line #: 98
[LOG] Finished reading lang/en/global-phrases.lang
[LOG] Reading... global-errors
[LOG] Finished reading lang/en/global-errors.lang
[LOG] Reading... global-menu
[LOG] Finished reading lang/en/global-menu.lang
[LOG] Reading... global-welcome
.
.
.
```

Any help in preparing desktop entry is highly appreciated

Comment: You should set `Terminal=false` as it's not a console application. Also, `NoDisplay=false` is not required, and `Name[en]` is not meant to be the file name of the .desktop file. It should also be _Stencyl_ there (or you can just remove that line as well).

Comment: @dobey - i did the same thing, still not working..                [Desktop Entry]
Name=Stencyl
Type=Application
Exec=~/opt/Stencyl/Stencyl
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/Stencyl/icon.xpm
Comment=Game Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE
Name[en]=Stencyl                         Do you know how to execute ./file from different directory, because of this exec is not able to execute the Stencyl file (as it is executable file)

Comment: If i try to run from other directory i get this error - amulbhatia@Nadar:/usr/share/applications$ /opt/Stencyl/Stencyl
Error: Unable to access jarfile ./sw.jar
May be because of sw.jar the .desktop file is not executing, please help

Comment: Thanks for your time, i wrote a shell script and executed the script from .desktop file, and same is working fine from launchpad now, may be otherway, but my work has been done, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Path=/opt/Stencyl` to the .desktop file.